# Simulation of aberration in axicon lens system

Tags: numerical-integration, simulation

Is it possible to simulate [axicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axicon) in mathematica and analyzed different properties like the aberration?

Comment: Depends what do you mean by simulate and analyze, please make sure the problem is precisely stated. See [asking guidelines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in case of doubts.

Comment: If you want to simulate Fresnel or Fraunhoffer diffraction, including aberrations, yes, you can do it with MMA...